# player doesnt flip after animations are added

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

[animator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h76NB.png)
so im new in unity and im trynig to make my first game. so i made a code for flipping the player and it worked good, but when i added animations to the player  it just stopped working! here is everything in my code relatable to the topic:

```
    public bool facingLeft = false;
    void flip()
    {
        facingLeft = !facingLeft;
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (facingLeft == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            flip();
        }
        if (facingRight == true && moveInput > 0)
        {
           flip();
        } 
    }
```

pls help, thx

Comment: Where is `moveInput` defined at?

Comment: ``` void FixedUpdate()
{
    moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
} ```

Comment: Start method should be `Start`, Not `start`

Comment: its capital s in the code i accidently wrote it wromg here

Comment: 1. Can you copy and paste your code in? Its hard to determine what the issue is if you accidently make more mistakes in typing it in. 2. Can you add a `Debug.Log("flipped")` in the flip function to see if it is working. 3. Are there any errors in the debugger? You need to give more debugging information here to get better help.

Comment: 1. i fixed it now so  there should not be any problems 2. its doesnt work 3. i get tons of errors that say "player' AnimationEvent has no function name specified" p.s i added a picture of the animator to text if its any help

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do define your animator but dont use it in the flip, you could or make it so that in the animation that the player moves and rotates accordingly to your stuff. like set the animation position itself.

Comment: can u please be more specific about what i need to do, like what exactly should i do, as i said, im new to unity so i can barely do anyythung without a tutorial

Comment: just search up, player movement animation. or just go into the animator and press record, move the position and it will set the current frame position of the object to that position.

Comment: but the animations work fine! the problem that after i added it the player only looking right and never left

Comment: Have you tried to first move right and then left? because your code is coded so that always the facing right is true. so you need to first make the face right false to be able to move left

Comment: can i see your animator

Comment: i added the image link in the text

Comment: i see that you have those things, but why dont you use the animator???

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: look, your problem is that you never check if the player is facing left, the whole system is right based. you cant check if isFacingRIght is false if it starts as true. you need to or create a new variable or set isFacingRight to false if there is left sided input (negetive horizontal input)

Comment: no i am not, i just dont know what is wrong. i have a feeling its not in the code. i need to think and i will get back to you in a moment

Comment: chenged it in the text

Comment: The code looks good, but why do you change the bool value of the facings in the flip? and how to you check if the player is facing left?

Comment: hi, i just fixed everything by using the animator(insted of just having player_idle i also added  player_idle_left) so at the end everything is working it was just a lot harder method. thanks for your help

Comment: that is what i was trying to tell you, just use the animator. im glad everything worked out. no problem